# How can I show the data of the cartItems by their id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these cart items where there could be the same products with multiple colors in the cart. Like this:
[image]

How can I display it where it will display the product name, size, and category once, then below it are the different colors along with their quantity. Something like this:

- Product ID
- Tumbler 500 ML
- Green : 4 (button to add and remove product) and the total
- Pink : 5 (button to add and remove product) and the total
- Black: 6 (button to add and remove product) and the total

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-sampled-2-efqrhd?file=/src/Cart.js:67-1764

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems, handleCartClearance, handleRemove, handleAdd }) => {
  console.log(cartItems, "items");

  const totalAmount = cartItems.reduce(
    (price, item) => price + item.quantity * item.price,
    0
  );

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(cartItems, "order");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Order page
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
          <Button onClick={handleCartClearance}>Clear Orders</Button>
        )}
        {cartItems.length === 0 && <div>No Items in the cart</div>}
        <div>
          {cartItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id + item.color}>
              <li>{item.id}</li>
              <li>{item.name + " " + item.size + "" + item.cat}</li>
              <li>{item.color}</li>
              <li>{item.quantity}</li>

              <li>Total: {Number(item.quantity) * Number(item.price)}</li>
              <button
                onClick={(e) =>
                  handleAdd(
                    item.id,
                    item.prodName,
                    item.price,
                    item.size,
                    item.cat,
                    item.color
                  )
                }
              >
                +
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => handleRemove(item)}>- </button>
            </div>
          ))}
          -----------------------------------------------------
          <div>
            <b>Total Amount :{totalAmount}</b>
          </div>
          {cartItems.length >= 1 && <Button type="submit">Save Order</Button>}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: u can use reduce and group the cartItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-sampled-2-forked-zzcnpf

```
{Object.entries(
  cartItems.reduce((prev, item) => {
    if (!prev[item.id]) prev[item.id] = { ...item, nest: [] };
    prev[item.id].nest.push(item);
    return prev;
  }, {})
).map(([id, obj], idx) => (
  <div key={id + obj.color}>
    <li>{obj.id}</li>
    <li>{obj.name + " " + obj.size + "" + obj.cat}</li>
    {obj.nest.map((nest, idx) => (
      <React.Fragment key={idx}>
        <li>{nest.color}</li>
        <li>{nest.quantity}</li>

        <li>Total: {Number(nest.quantity) * Number(nest.price)}</li>
        <button
          onClick={(e) =>
            handleAdd(
              nest.id,
              nest.prodName,
              nest.price,
              nest.size,
              nest.cat,
              nest.color
            )
          }
        >
          +
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleRemove(nest)}>- </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```